# Error Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, android-room

I'm have the problem which concluded in that I'm can't build the project because of the following error, which occured when I'm add `suspend` keyword to the `addNumber` method in the data access object:

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
                                                    ^
```

My dao:

```
typealias NumberListLiveData = LiveData<List<Number>>

@Dao
interface NumbersDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addNumber(number: Number)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM numbers_table")
    fun getAllNumbers(): NumberListLiveData

}
```

My entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "numbers_table")
data class Number(
    @PrimaryKey(true)
    val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    val value: Int
)
```

Build.gradle.ktx:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.ilya.room"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.ilya.room"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), 
"proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    val roomVersion = "2.5.2"
    
    // Coroutines 
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4")

    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: What is the rest of the error log?

Comment: error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.  kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);                                                                                                              
error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
public abstract java.lang.Object addNumber(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Answer (score 0):

There is a type in **Kotlin** `Number` that clashes with the one defined by you.

To verify this, specify your type with the whole package name e.g. `com.example.app.model.Number`

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun addNumber(number: com.example.app.model.Number)
```

If this will fix it, just make sure you import it, so it will overshadow the kotlin type.

```
import com.example.app.model.Number
```

Comment: Number is in the same package with Dao class, and error log is marking `$completion` object as error reason. I tried do that you recommended me, but it whatever doesn't helped

Comment: @Илья Жиленков Check if you are using your `Number` in the definition of the database(`@Database(entities = [...]`).